# how to print registered icon in Handlebars

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js

I am trying to use handlebars to build out some HTML.  I have this content:

```
Some message here &reg;
```

and I have tried {{ and {{{ to escape it, but I keep getting gibberish.  Does anyone know the cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: Can you include some of the code that you've tried besides the {{ and {{{?

Comment: i have also just copy pasted a registration mark in, which works except that it also has a strange character in front of it.  I haven't really known what else to do.

Comment: I see that you're trying to print the sign for a registered trademark. Can you provide a link to a screenshot of what that looks like?